# Mongoose, query for embedded array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
groupsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
     name: String,
     books: [{
       _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
       title: String,
       filename: String
     }]
  });
```

I need a query, something like this:

```
db.Groups.findOne({name: group_name, 'books.title': book_title},
{_id: 0, 'books._id.$': 1}, function(err, book) {}
```

To get a one book id where title = book_title.
Right now it gives me one wrong book with all attributes. Without $ it gives me all books id.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using? 3.2?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. What caused problems is:

> **"Only one array field may appear in the query document."**

I was also checking members array (not present in example). This:

```
db.Groups.findOne({name: group_name, 'books.title': book_title},
{_id: 0, 'books.$': 1}
```

works fine.